# What is the current best solution to clear floats, such as "<div style='clear: both'></div>"?

Tags: css, css-float

I have used

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

to clear the floats... and have seen cases where it is

```
<div style="clear: both; height: 1px; line-height: 1px"></div>
```

and have seen clearfix, and some with a hidden `.` and make it the same color as the background.  Now Compass and Blueprint also have a `+clearfix`.  What is the current best way to clear floats, now that probably we don't need to support IE 6?

Comment: with the first kind of clear:both , i had problems in IE7 too , it added height , then i used your second approach to give height as 1px;

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, I mostly use overflow or float the parent element. There is no best solution.

Comment: can you give a short example of them or point to a webpage that talks about it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually like the method explained here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html. It get's away from adding an extra element to the html.

Answer (score 1):

I have learned that 
  `content: "";`
  `display: table;`
  `clear: both;`
work with all browsers after IE 8+

Answer (score 0):

I like [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).  Read this too (which I didn't know about until just now):  [Everything you Know about Clearfix is Wrong](http://thinkvitamin.com/design/everything-you-know-about-clearfix-is-wrong/).